Fatal Error on Fresh Install of Open Web Analytics - Uncaught Error: Class 'Monolog\Logger' not found
I was following the installation instructions on the Open Web Analytics (OWA) website (https://github.com/Open-Web-Analytics/Open-Web-Analytics/wiki/Installation) at step 3 - "Start the installation wizard by pointing your web browser at: http://yourdomain/path/to/owa/install.php."
My system: OWA 1.7.8 (installed from owa_1.7.8.tar download), PHP 7.4.3, Apache 2.4.41, MySQL 8.0.36, Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.
The Apache error log:
[Tue Jun 11 08:42:48.243603 2024] [php7:error] [pid 781166] [client 73.221.222.250:44656] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Monolog\Logger' not found in /var/www/html/owa/modules/base/classes/error.php:68\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/owa/owa_lib.php(489): owa_error->__construct()\n#1 /var/www/html/owa/owa_coreAPI.php(487): owa_lib::factory()\n#2 /var/www/html/owa/owa_coreAPI.php(158): owa_coreAPI::supportClassFactory()\n#3 /var/www/html/owa/owa_base.php(77): owa_coreAPI::errorSingleton()\n#4 /var/www/html/owa/owa_caller.php(76): owa_base->__construct()\n#5 /var/www/html/owa/owa.php(24): owa_caller->__construct()\n#6 /var/www/html/owa/index.php(35): owa->__construct()\n#7 {main}\n thrown in /var/www/html/owa/modules/base/classes/error.php on line 68

I installed an info.php file in the root of the owa site, and I can access it from a browser. I also tested accessing the mysql using the OWA user, and that works.
I posted to the OWA Issues section of the site, but no response. I thought someone in this space may have had a similar issue. I am not a PHP guy, so the error message just tells me something is missing, but everything should have been in the tar file I downloaded.

Did you use the stock version of their repository (which hasn't seen any release since way over a year!), and are you sure you've followed their installation steps completely? Then please report this as a bug in their issue tracker. Also, keep in mind that PHP 7.4.3 is horribly outdated and should not be in use since years

Issue already reported here and there.

Generally, this isn't the right place if you want to report bugs. Since you're just using the system, that would be the case here. For a proper Q here, you'd be expected to isolate the problem first, too.

@UlrichEckhardt I included the error log from Apache, which should give someone proficient in PHP an indication of what is wrong. As I mentioned in the original post, I am not a PHP guy, so I am asking help in figuring out what is wrong. I am not posting a bug report for OWA in this forum.

The issues referenced by @Olivier above are for PHP 8.x.x and the OWA folks clearly point out that OWA does not work with PHP 8.x.x. It is supposed to work with PHP 7.x.x, which I am using.

Please share how you started the installation. Did you check whether there is any vendor folder in your installation?

It was a first time installation, so no vendor folder.

Did you run composer install to create a vendor folder? Isn't it obvious that the files from the vendor folder can't be run if it does not exist?

You have downloaded the wrong package. The release page provides three files:

owa_1.7.8_packaged.tar
Source code (zip)
Source code (tar.gz)

You picked the third one (which has no vendor directory) instead of the first one (which does contain it). All the application dependencies are contained in that directory (monolog being one of them).

I am sure I downloaded the first one, as I did not want the source code. I mistyped the file name above. I can't check, as I deleted all the OWA stuff and moved on to Matomo. The Matomo installation was very smooth and I was up and running is short amount of time.
